# Result of function made by createTransformer from mobx-utils is not memoized

Tags: mobx, mobx-utils

I am trying to implement computed getter function with argument like [shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49528383/506695) with MobX 6 and corresponding version of `mobx-utils`.

```js
export class CodificatorStore {
  @observable.ref items: Array<Codificator> | null = null;

  @action setItems(items: Array<Codificator>): void {
    this.items = items;
  }

  @computed get item(): ITransformer<number, Codificator | null> {
    return createTransformer((index: number): Codificator | null => {
      console.log(`get item by index: ${index}`);
      return this.items ? this.items[index] : null;
    });
  }
}
```

I expected created function to memoize the result of its execution each time I call it with the same argument and the same (not changed) observable `items` but I get a new logged message on each call in render method of my React component:

```
codificatorStore.item(0);
```

According to [docs](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils#createtransformer-in-detail) and [source code](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils/blob/3a1ee03527950a44c5ce57007344a56a9b974c94/src/create-transformer.ts#L96-L98) I expect that memoized value should be returned from `reactiveView` on all consecutive calls instead of invoking my transform function. Do I misunderstand something? How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do you really need to memoize such simple operation? Or is it just an example?

Second, if you need just to memoize you don't need `createTransformer` at all, it serves a bit different purpose. But you can use `computedFn`, like that:

```js
import { computedFn } from 'mobx-utils';

// ...

  item = computedFn((index) => {
    console.log(`get item by index: ${index}`);
    return this.items ? this.items[index] : null;
  });
```

[Example on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-70435314-g9nyw?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I already have luck with `computedFn`. And yes, I just simplified the example, the real calculations are more difficult and expensive.